# How to stop auto-sorting import commands in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, auto-import

In PyCharm, when we use auto-import feature, a new import command is inserted and the whole import commands get sorted.

I want those commands as-is ie. not sorted. How to stop it in PyCharm?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this, because the auto sorting is done as per PEP-8 (see [this link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)).

Comment: I indeed don't want to follow PEP or PIP or any standard that not make sense

Comment: Then don't use the auto-import feature, its that simple =)

Comment: Your reasoning is funny ^^ Thanks for sharing.